# Backup Office 365 SharePoint site for move to local hosting

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup

I have a Office 365 SharePoint site that I need to backup in its entirety. All the information I can find on this is at least a couple of years old.

With a local SharePoint site this is easy to accomplish from Central Administration but I can find no built in way to do the same other than save the site as a template but this runs into the 50MB max size limitation.

Comment: You might try some of these ideas: http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2011/10/10/how-to-back-up-office-365-sharepoint-online-data.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a simple method available in SharePoint Online to backup your site collections.You can think about one of the option:

1. Use the 3rd party tools to move the sites from online to local.i.e. ShareGate or Metalogix etc.(some offer free trial).
2. Contact the SharePoint Online support and see if they give you the backup files.
3. Another method is, Manual move the data from Online to local.
4. Or you can save each list / library individually and then restore in the same structure way...this required alot of effort.

*Note: Even if you able to get the Backup file of SharePoint online site collection but you will not able to restore it to your local farm. Reason: SharePoint Online always higher build version so that's why 3rd party tools will be best option.

Comment: And you will have different features activated online that you don't have on Prem.